# Dojo addOnLoad, but is Dojo loaded?

Tags: dom, dojo, onload

I've encountered what seems like a chicken & egg problem, and have what I think is a logical solution.  However, it occurred to me that others must have encountered something similar, so I figured I'd float it out there for the masses.

The situation is that I want to use dojo's addOnLoad function to queue up a number of callbacks which should be executed after the DOM has completed rendering on the client side.  So what I'm doing is as follows:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="dojo.xd.js"></script>
        ...
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
        <script type="text/javascript">
            dojo.addOnLoad( ... );
            dojo.addOnLoad( ... );
            ...
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now, the issue is that I seem to be calling dojo.addOnLoad before the entire Dojo library has been downloaded the browser.  This makes sense in a way, because the inline SCRIPT contents should be executed *before* the entire DOM is loaded (and the normal body onload callback is triggered).

My question is this - is my approach sound, or would it make more sense to register a normal/standard body onload JavaScript callback to call a function, which does the same work that each of the dojo.addOnLoads is doing in the SCRIPT block.  Of course, this begs the question, why would you ever then use dojo.addOnLoad if you're not guaranteed that the Dojo library will be loaded prior to using the library?

Hopefully this situation makes sense to someone other than me.  Seems like someone else may have encountered this situation.

Thoughts?

Best Regards,
Adam Rice

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're doing it correctly. External Javascript files are loaded and executed synchronously in order, so by the time it reaches your `dojo.addOnLoad( ... );` Dojo has loaded. Use `dojo.addOnLoad` instead of `window.onload` for two reasons:

- it fires earlier, because it utilizes [DOMContentLoaded](http://dojotoolkit.org/2006/08/21/domcontentloaded-now-onload-event-dojo)
- it handles asynchronous loading of `dojo.require` by postponing the execution until all required scripts have been read

Explained in DojoCampus as ([dojo.addOnLoad](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojo/addOnLoad)):

> dojo.addOnLoad is a fundamental aspect
>   of using Dojo. Passing addOnLoad a
>   function will register the function to
>   run when the Dom is ready. This
>   differs slightly from document.ready
>   and body.onload in that addOnLoad
>   waits until all dojo.require() (and
>   their recursive dependencies) have
>   loaded before firing.

Answer (score -5):

This might have nothing to do with your problem, but ive just had a case where I had the same symptoms. For me everything worked fine for Firefox, Chrome etc, but not IE8.

I was getting what looked like dojo not being loaded, an error in IE8 saying that dojo was undefined (but not all the time) and i could strip everything down to just style sheets and importing dojo and still get the error.

I was running a local google app engine development server. This looks to be based on pythons SimpleHTTPServer which in turn uses SocketServer.BaseServer. This has BaseServer.request_queue_size which defaults to 5 - i couldn't find anything in app engine which overrode this value so i guess the development google app engine server has an upper limit of 5 connections.

Using regedit and going to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings

“MaxConnectionsPerServer”=dword:00000010
“MaxConnectionsPer1_0Server”=dword:0000010

This shows that IE was going to try and open up to 10 simultaneous connections. I edited these two keys and made them 2 and restarted the computer, the problem went away.