# Does anyone have a simple example of a working DojoX Grid control?

Tags: grid, dojo

I'm trying to add a DojoX Grid control to my website, but I can't get it to work.  I'd like a simple example to start from, but there doesn't seem to *be* one anywhere.  These are my requirements:

1. I need an example of the 1.2 Grid
2. It should load the Dojo libraries from `googleapis.com` (or AOL's servers; not the trunk code or the Dojo code hosted one some private server)
3. Other than loading the Dojo code from a public server, all the rest of the code should be contained in the HTML page.  No loading data from another URL; I'm trying to get the Grid working; *then* I'll worry about dynamically loading data.

Amazingly, I can't find anything that meets all three requirements.  Does anything know of one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

1. Started with the standard [Dojox Grid test page](http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/grid/tests/test_data_grid_large.html)
2. Fixed CSS imports a la:

   @import "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.2.3/dojox/grid/resources/Grid.css";
3. Loaded cross domain Dojo:

   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.2.3/dojo/dojo.xd.js" djConfig="isDebug:false, parseOnLoad: false">
4. ...with parseOnLoad set to false.
5. Imported function that declares `test_store` and gave it a name:

   loadStore = function(){
     // some sample data
6. Started everything once all `dojo.require`d classes had loaded:

   dojo.addOnLoad( function(){
   loadStore();
   dojo.parser.parse()
   } );

And that's it: a working [Dojo Grid using cross domain library demo](http://1013.fi/ajax/demo/test_data_grid_large.html).